# ruby not equal operator doesn't work but equal does

Tags: ruby

I'm very puzzled with this simple method I have where I'm just trying to puts a character of an array if, when compared with the character of another array, it is different.

This works with the == operator but not with the !=

Maybe it has to do with the each loops but I can't see what the error is. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
def remove_vowels(s)
 nw_s = s.chars
 vowels = "aeiou".chars
 result = []
  nw_s.each do |char|
    vowels.each do |vowel|
      if char != vowel
        print char
      end
    end
  end
end

remove_vowels("apple")
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested each is no ruby way of doing this kind of task. You can write this

```
def remove_vowels(s)
  nw_s = s.chars
  vowels = "aeiou".chars
  result = nw_s.map {|k| k unless vowels.include?(k) }.compact
end

remove_vowels("apple")
```

One line of code instead seven

Comment: Or just `"apple".scan(/[aeiou]/).join`

Comment: It returns 'ae', and Peter want to remove vowels from string

Comment: Okay `"apple".scan(/[^aeiou]/).join` then.

Comment: `"apple".delete("aeiou")`